# Aurelia binding expression syntax in detail

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to find a single reference for the Aurelia framework that describes the syntax of binding expressions in as much detail as possible, but haven't really found anything that goes into the right level of detail.

Ideally I'd like something that describes the production rules for the AST created by the parser (without having to read the source code myself!)

Comment: Have you already looked into http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-how-it-works/3 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NyxGZYgOCuo&feature=youtu.be ?

Comment: the links @MarcScheib provided should rather thoroughly answer your question.

Comment: The AST Demo included in the first link is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.